# cannot create jquery ui tabs in foreach loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to create some [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) using data fetched from a database. I know I can create tabs like this (from the jQuery ui site):

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
</div>
```

But let's say that `tabs-1, tabs-2, and tabs-3` were data that were comming from a database and that I wanted to generate the tabs dynamically.

I tried something like:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
foreach($tabs as $tab)
{
    <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $tab['index']; ?>">Tabs <?php echo $tab['index']; ?></a></li>
}
</ul>
<div id="tabs-<?php echo $tab['index']; ?>">This is tab: <?php echo $tab['index']; ?></div> 
</div>
```

But the problem I'm having is that I only get the last div in my loop created (the other divs before are not there). Anybody knows what the problem is here?

Thank you

Comment: Your foreach isn't within PHP tags (`<?php...?>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you should do another loop to print the tabs, like this you're only printing the last one.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>

        foreach($tabs as $tab)
        {
            <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $tab['index']; ?>">Tabs <?php echo $tab['index']; ?></a></li>
        }
    </ul>
        foreach($tabs as $tab)
        {
             <div id="tabs-<?php echo $tab['index']; ?>">This is tab: <?php echo $tab['index']; ?></div> 
        }
 </div>
```

That's a php problem by the way! ;) **Your syntax doesn't seems correct** but i putted it the same way, you should use PHP tags or the echo function

Answer (score 0):

You are failing to loop over the DIVs that represent the tab content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over `$tabs` twice, once to print out the links and once to print out the content:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <? foreach($tabs as $tab): ?>
      <li><a href="#tabs-<?=$tab['index'];?>">Tabs <?=$tab['index'];?></a></li>
    <? endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
  <? foreach($tabs as $tab): ?>
      <div id="tabs-<?=$tab['index'];?>">This is the content of tab <?=$tab['index'];?></div>
  <? endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jerome, I was trying to provide a working (and complete) answer. When I started writing this your answer was about as complete as Marc's, and even with your edits it's not actually syntax correct.

Comment: Ok np,yes i know that the syntax is not correct that what i said below my answer ;)